# Investigate the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $n+1\over (n^3+2)^{1\over 2}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Investigate the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $n+1\over (n^3+2)^{1\over 2}$.

Since $n+1<n^2$ and $(n^3+2)^{1\over 2}>n^{3\over 2}$ for all $n\ge2$, then we can compare the above seres to $n^2\over n^{3/2}$$=$$n^{1\over 2}$ which is a divergent series. Thus by the comparison test we know that the original series is divergent.

Does this make sense. Any hints/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have concluded $S<\text{divergent series}$. $S$ is divergent does not follow.

Comment: I see where I went wrong.

Comment: Good! So you see that we needed to compare to a lesser divergent series to conclue that our series is divergent. The are several answers describing this :)

Comment: @Gino . Please ensure to upvote answers which you found to be helpful and accept the one you find helpful most. It is only polite to do so, as this will make things easier for people who are looking for answers to similar questions in the future. Also, it helps give credit where credit is due :)

Comment: Your bounding $n+1<n^2$ is too loose. $n+1$ is essentially $n$ (first degree), while $n^2$ is second degree, with a much faster growth. $n+1<2n$ would be better. Often you can simply keep the term of higher degree of the polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the series is divergent, but  $$n^{1/2}>  \dfrac{n+1}{(n^3 + 2)^{1/2}}$$

so we'll find a divergent series $\sum b_n$ such that $$\dfrac {n+1}{(n^3 + 2)^{1/2}} > b_n$$ Note that $\dfrac{n+1}{(n^3 + 2)^{1/2}}\,>\,\dfrac 1{n^{1/2}}$, and since  $\sum \dfrac 1{n^{1/2}}$ diverges by the $p$-test, so too does our series.

Comment: But you can use it with the Limit Comparison Test.

Comment: You know I am not speaking about the limit comparison test, @Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the series diverges, since $\frac{n+1}{(n^3+2)^{1/2}} \approx \frac{n}{n^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. So, we need to bound the series below by something that also diverges; a clever direct comparison is
$$ \frac{n+1}{(n^3+2)^{1/2}} > \frac{n+1}{(n(n+1)^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{n+1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}. $$

And of course, the divergence of $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is established by the "p-test".

Answer (score 0):

Your way isn't correct cause you can't raise the numerator since then each term is bigger then the one from original series,also you can't make the denominator smaller since then that number is bigger then the original one.So you either make numerator smaller and/or denominator bigger.
Anyway notice $n^3+2\leq n^4$ for $n\geq2$ so you have that
$$\frac{n+1}{(n^4)^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\geq\frac{n+1}{(n^3+2)^{1/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the consider a plot of the functions corresponding to the sequence $(a_n) = \displaystyle \bigg(\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)$ as well as our given sequence $(b_n)=\bigg( \frac{n+1}{(n^3 +2)^\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)$ respectively.

[image: Comparison]

Looking at the plot given above we can see that, eventually $$\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{2}} < \frac{n+1}{(n^3 +2)^\frac{1}{2}}$$

Notice, however, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{2}}$ diverges (read up [$p$-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series)).

We can thus, using the Limit Comparison Test, conclude that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{(n^3 +2)^\frac{1}{2}}$ diverges.